# post the second duplicate in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following statement

`SELECT whatweek, username, team FROM weekpicks GROUP BY  team, username HAVING count(*) > 1 ORDER BY 'whatweek' asc`

the out put will find all of the duplicates with in the table for the user but it the list does not output only the second occurrence.  some times it will post 1st occurrence and others is 2nd occurrence.  I need it to post only the second occurrence.

Comment: This select works? You don't have an error for column whatweek?

Comment: yes this select works, no errors. Just not selecting the right value I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may calculate needed whatweek in subquery

```
    SELECT (
        SELECT whatweek 
        FROM weekpicks t
        WHERE t.username = weekpicks.username 
        AND t.team = weekpicks.team
        ORDER BY whatweek DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS `needed_whatweek`, 
        username, team 
    FROM weekpicks 
    GROUP BY team, username 
    HAVING count(*) > 1
```

**EDIT** Or use MAX(), its preffer I think:

```
SELECT MAX(whatweek), username, team FROM weekpicks 
GROUP BY team, username HAVING count(*) > 1
```